# Error Message for Tor Windows

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, error

Can someone help me? I downloaded Tor Browser for windows, it ran fine for a few hours then a error message saying "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022)". I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try (temporarily) turning off any antivirus software you have installed. See the following threads for similar answers:

- [Error message "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022)." whenever I try to open Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6587/error-message-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc0000022-when)
- [The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022)](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4912/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc0000022)